# passing servlet values to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get values to a drop down list based on the previous value selected from another drop down list. I am able to call to java class from the servlet and the values are returned to servlet but it is not getting passed down to jsp page

jsp page part(index.jsp)

```
<select id="region" name="region" class="form-control" onchange="getgroups()" required="required" >
<option value="" default selected>Select region</option>
<option value="region1">region1</option>
<option value="region2">region2</option>
<option value="region3">region3</option>
<option value="region4">region4</option></select>
```

The onchange value in region calls this function

```
function getgroups(){

var j = document.getElementById("region");
var s = document.getElementById("secret_key");
var a = document.getElementById("access_key");

   var output = $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:8066/VMMigratorNew/ec2util',
     data: {"region":j.value,
            "secret_key":s.value,
            "access_key":a.value,
            },
     success: function(response) {
         return output.responseText;
     }

});

}
```

and in servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String region = request.getParameter("region");
        String secretKey = request.getParameter("secret_key");
        String accessKey = request.getParameter("access_key");




            List<String> vpcs = RunEc2Command.getVPCForUSer(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, region);

            if(vpcs != null && vpcs.size() > 0) {
                                request.setAttribute("vpclist", vpcs);
            }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

and in the same index.jsp page , I am trying to show the list values in a drop down box which is in index.jsp itself.

```
          <select id="vpc" name="vpc" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose VPC"  >
                                        <option value="" default selected>Select VPC</option>

                                            <c:forEach items="${vpclist}" var="vpcs">    
                                                 <option>
                                                   ${vpcs}
                                                 </option>
                                            </c:forEach> 
                                    </select>
```

I need to get the value of VPC in drop dron box  after selecting the value from region drop down box. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You have a trailing `--%>` in your JSP. And the AJAX callback doesn't do anything with the response it receives. It must replace the existing select box by the one received in the response.

Comment: I have removed that trailing . It is still not working.

Comment: Define "not working" precisely. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JB Nizet . I will select a value from a drop down box  in JSP page and on selecting that value , I have to get values in another drop down box based the value selected previoulsy. The problem is I am not able to populate the values in drop down box.

Comment: Have you read my previous comment: "the AJAX callback doesn't do anything with the response it receives. It must replace the existing select box by the one received in the response.". Have you at least verified that the AJAX request was sent, was correctly handled by the server, and returned the appropriate HTML? Use console.log(). User your JavaScript debugger. Use the Network tab of the browser dev tools to see what requests are made and what responses are received.

Comment: The ajax call works fine , it is fetching the value from the RUNEC2command class and I am able to see the values in servlet. Please tell me what should I do with the AJAX call.... I am very new to servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the workflow in your servlet is suitable for a synchronous request, which requires the servlet to return the whole HTML in the HTTP response for the browser to render. However, it seems to me that your intent is instead of querying the servlet in order to obtain a VPC list, and you are trying to pose the query asynchronously using AJAX.

Hence, my suggestion would be to let the servlet return the VPC list in some format (e.g., JSON). In the `success` callback, you should modify the DOM in order to insert the list you received.

Comment: I dont know JSON . Can u show me how it can be done.

Comment: You need to construct a JSON representation of the list (using, e.g., the standard JEE JSON API), and use the `response` object to send back such JSON to the browser.

Comment: how to access the JSON array in jsp page and put in drop down box

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing server-side and client-side computation. The AJAX request is made at the client-side and must be handled at the client-side, which means that you should handle the JSON returned from the servlet in the `success` callback of your jsp page.

Comment: If you can explain that in detail, it would be helpful.